# SpecialCells(12).Value stops after first hidden row

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm currently trying to copy a filtered column to an array to populate a ComboBox in a Powerpoint presentation.
The line of code I'm using to do this is:

```
ar = tbl.ListColumns(ColNumber).Range.SpecialCells(12).Value
```

Where "ar" is the destination array, "tbl" is the source table and "ColNumber" is the number of column I'm trying to copy.

The filtered column I'm trying to copy has around 180 records but I noticed the destination array has 6 values since it selected only until the first "hidden" row in the range, and skipped every other visible row after that.

Is there a way to get the value of every visible row and not just the first ones?

Comment: set a break point and type `? tbl.ListColumns(ColNumber).Range.address` in the direct window to check if `tbl` contains all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing that issue because of Non Contigous range. You **cannot** use the method `Array = Range.Value` for Non Contigous range. There are two ways you can follow to achieve what you want.

**WAY 1** Identify the Range, Loop through the cells and populate the array. Suitable for your case as you are dealing with single column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, ColNumber As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant table
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    '~~> Change to relevant column number
    ColNumber = 1
    
    '~~> Autofilter as required
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=ColNumber, Criteria1:="Blah1"
    
    '~~> Set your range
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(ColNumber).Range.SpecialCells(12)
    
    '~~> Get the count of cells in that range
    n = rng.Cells.Count
        
    '~~> Resize the array to hold the data
    ReDim ar(1 To n)
        
    n = 1
        
    '~~> Store the values from that range into the array
    For Each aCell In rng.Cells
        ar(n) = aCell.Value
        n = n + 1
    Next aCell
    
    For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
        Debug.Print ar(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**WAY 2** Identify the Range, loop thorough the [Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas) and then loop through the cells in that `Area` and then populate the array. Very similar to the above code.

**In Action**

[image]